# Tabcollapse inside accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's the first time I post here because I'm really getting stuck on a project: I build a website based on the bootstrap accordion. The content in here is loaded in bootstrap tabs which transform into an accordion itself on mobile. So it's a tabcollapse, I use this one: http://tabcollapse.okendoken.com/example/example.html

A test of the tabcollapse outside of the parent bootstrap accordion worked fine, but the problem is that inside it doesn't: tabs still work but on mobile resolution the accordion won't show. It only shows up after I resize the browser window again while it should work directly on load. On a mobile phone it shows, but only after a couple of seconds...

Here's the opening part of the (big) code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">First accordion link</a>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">TAB1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">TAB2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">TAB3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">TAB4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content" >
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">Content inside first tabcollapse panel.......
```

So am I doing something wrong or isn't it possible to use a tabcollapse inside an accordion? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you closed all the opened <div> tags ?

Comment: Yes, I just pasted the opening part of the code to save some space in the post. I now know the tabcollapse works when a panel is opened on page load so there seems a conflict with a hidden panel. I'm still stuck.